# Refactor classes into a separate project

Tags: java, refactoring

I intend to extract several classes and packages from one Java project and place them into another (which will have a distributable jar). That much isn't too difficult, but of course with such a large refactoring there are consequences. Namely there are many classes in the original project that are subclasses of the classes I want to extract. What's the best method for approaching this sort of refactoring?

Comment: The extracted jar must be included in the original project as dependency.

Comment: What IDE are you using ?

Comment: Why does the IDE matter?

Comment: @LuGo The IDE doesn't help you in taking refactoring decisions, but they correct and maintain all references, to classes, packages, etc., so you don't have to, making the process more easy.

Comment: @user1598390 I am using Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically this is what I did:

1. Create a new project
2. Copy over the appropriate classes from the old project to a new package in the new project, reconfigure until everything builds
3. Test that project separately and build it in to a jar
4. add jar as a dependency
5. Delete the classes from the original project
6. Manually change all the imports from the old packages to the new packages

What I was really looking for was some way to automate or streamline step 6 to make sure I didn't break anything, but I'm not sure it exists beyond mass find/replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate projects and the main project will have dependencies for all these projects. So in your IDE you can navigate through source code easily.

When building your application, each dependency could be built into a `jar` and the main application will be bundled with all the dependents jars in its classpath.

Let take as example a web app using plugins, and plugins using common classes, utilities and so on stored in a project named common-plugins.

```
project/webapp: having dependency on plugin1, plugin2 and common-plugin
project/plugin1: having dependency on common-plugins
project/plugin2: having dependency on common-plugins
project/common-plugins: having no dependencies
```

When building your project, you could build the plugins and the common-plugins into jars, bundled with your web app

```
project/webapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/plugin1.jar
project/webapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/plugin2.jar
project/webapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/common-plugins.jar
```

This way in your IDE, I will take eclipse for instance, you will have a workspace having 4 projects with dependencies as described above. At build using maven, ant, ivy, or what you want, you will build the 3 projects that the webapp project depends on, then bundle the whole stuff.